# PowerShell: How To Create A Reference on Object Properties

Tags: shell, pointers, powershell, command-line, reference

## Some Facts:

When you asign an object to a variable called `$a` and then one of it's propertys changes, the variable `$a` gets updated.

But when I asign the value of an object's *property* `$object.property` (instead of the object itself) to the variable called `$b` and then `$object.property` changes, `$b` doesn't get updated. That means, the current value is stored in `$object.property`, but `$b` stays the way it is.

## An example:

I asign an `Window` object to a variable called `$bochsWindow`. Then some propertys change because I move the window. But when I print out `$bochsWindow`, you can see that it's up to date - that means, all new values of the object's propertys are also stored in `$bochsWindow`.

But if try to store a property of `$bochsWindow` in a variable called `$posX` and then the property changes, `$posX` doesn't change.

```
PS .> $bochsWindow = (GetProcess bochs | Get-Window)
PS .> $bochsWindow


ProcessId    : 1536
ProcessName  : bochs
Position     : {X=54,Y=32,Width=650,Height=576}
IsMinimized  : False
IsMaximized  : False
WindowHandle : 3933134
Caption      : Bochs for Windows - Display


[[Moving Boch's Window By Hand]]
PS .> $bochsWindow


ProcessId    : 1536
ProcessName  : bochs
Position     : {X=0,Y=0,Width=650,Height=576}
IsMinimized  : False
IsMaximized  : False
WindowHandle : 3933134
Caption      : Bochs for Windows - Display


PS .> (Get-Window -ProcessName bochs)


ProcessId    : 1536
ProcessName  : bochs
Position     : {X=0,Y=0,Width=650,Height=576}
IsMinimized  : False
IsMaximized  : False
WindowHandle : 3933134
Caption      : Bochs for Windows - Display



PS .> $posX = $bochsWindow.Position.X
PS .> $posX
302
[[Moving Boch's Window By Hand]]
PS .> $posX
302
PS .> $bochsWindow.Position.X
472
PS .>
```

But what should I do if I want `$posX` to stay up to date and always store the new value (`472`) instead of `302`

## My Question:

I want to store a reference the an object's property in a variable. That means, I want the variable to get updated every time the object's property changes. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not trivial way using `PSBreakpoint`, but it's the only that I know:

```
$global:bochsWindow = (GetProcess bochs | Get-Window) 
$act= @'
$global:b = $bochsWindow.Position.X 
'@
$global:sb = [scriptblock]::Create($act)
$global:b = Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable b -Mode Read -Action $global:sb
```

In this way `$b` is always updated when called.

Comment: Why are you always writing `$global:` in front of the variable's name. Does that mean that your Breakpoint method is just usable on global vars?

Comment: @fridojet Because the variables must live in scriptblock too. Would otherwise be evaluated as new variables in scriptblock.

Comment: But: Would it be possible to omit `global:` if I just want to use the variable inside of the scriptblock solely?

Comment: @fridojet All the variables are used in scriptblock here. You can omit $global for the last $global:b = set-break.... and -Action $global:sb  because are declared as global before. No way else!

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I meant. I know that I need `$global:` in order to be able to use these variables outside of the scriptblock. But what if I just want to use `$b` inside of the scriptblock solely and nowhere else. That's why I wanted to make these variables local through omitting `global:`. Is that possible?

Comment: @fridojet if $b variable is used only in the scriptblock code you can omit $global.  Try reading `get-help about_scopes` for more informations.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just create a function?

```
function posX(){ $bochsWindow.Position.X }
```

And then use it as `posX`. Alternative would be a scriptblock.

Other than that, I don't see a straightforward way for doing this.